# Passing result from an interceptor to the next one in chain

Tags: java, interceptor, spring-aop, chain

Could please anyone suggest a way of doing that ? Let say that I'd wanted to pass the result of interceptorA invoke() method to interceptorB instead of having just the method invocation pass through both of them.

```
<bean id="personTarget" class="com.mycompany.PersonImpl">
    <property name="name" value="Tony"/>
    <property name="age" value="51"/>
</bean>

<bean id="interceptorA" class="com.example.MySampleInterceptor"/>
<bean id="interceptorB" class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.DebugInterceptor"/>

<bean id="person" 
    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.mycompany.Person"/>

    <property name="target" ref="personTarget"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>interceptorA</value>
            <value>interceptorB</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

One possible way seems to be ordering interceptors the other way around and doing :

```
public class DebugInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Before: invocation=[" + invocation + "]");
        Object rval = invocation.proceed();
        System.out.println("Invocation returned");
        return rval;
    }
}
```

has the first interceptor use result value of the previous one.